# Chance, that two-digit number number will divisible by 7

Tags: probability

First girl writes number from 1 to 8 on a blackboard. The second writes number from 1 to 8 left or right from first number. What is chance, that this two-digit number will divisible by 7? I solved it with two ways.

First: There are **9** two-digit numbers dividable by 7: **14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 56, 63, 77, 84.** All number possible combinations **8*8=64**. So chance is positive end divide by all possible, so chance is: **10/64**

Second: Let's calculate chances for each number, which was written by first girl. So:

1. Second can write 21 (left 2), 14 (right 4)
2. Second can write 21 (right 1), 28 (right 8), 42 (left 4)
3. Second can write 35 (right 5), 63 (left 6)

Later the same logic, but I'll write only possible numbers.

4. 84, 42, 14
5. 35, 56
6. 56, 63
7. 77
8. 84, 28

Let's summ this chances. For each first number can be 15 combinations. (**2*8-1**).

So 1/8*1/15+5/8*2/15+2/8*3/15=**17/120**

Comment: first way has 10 successes, not 9, you miscounted

Comment: @gt6989b I wrote wrong. 70 cannot be, because we can write numbers from 1 to 8.

Comment: I see no reason to assume equally likely cases. What if the first girl's favorite number is $7$, she will always write $7$; and the second girl will always write $3$. The result will be $37$ or $73$, the probability that it's divisible by $7$ is zero.

Comment: The problem says that two girls write numbers between $1$ and $8$. It does not say that they write them randomly, or with uniform distribution. If you want to add that stipulation to the problem, use the edit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way you calculated, there are 9 numbers out of 64 that are divisible by 7.$$p=9/64$$

The second way you calculated, you're missing that there are two ways to end up with the number 77 (7 to the right of 7, and 7 to the left of 7). Similarly, there's no reason to subtract 1 from the number of possible ways to create a 2-digit number from the first digit. Although there are only 15 possible resulting numbers, the possibility with two of the same digit is twice as likely as the rest. $$p=6/8*2/16+2/8*3/16=12/128+6/128=18/128=9/64$$